# Return Point type PSQL and DOCTRINE

Tags: php, symfony, orm, postgis, psql

I got an app that use POSTGIS Point value. I store it in my location table as coordinate. I can setup a new Point to database using Symfony and doctrine. The problem is the inverse, when I try to get te point on symfony I cant, the show me a blank value or null. I got the next configuration files:

Point.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\DBAL\Types\Geolocation;

class Point
{
    private $latitude;
    private $longitude;

    /**
     * Point constructor.
     */
    public function __construct($latitude, $longitude)
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;
        $this->longitude = $longitude;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLongitude()
    {
        return $this->longitude;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLatitude()
    {
        return $this->latitude;
    }
}
```

PointType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\DBAL\Types\PSQL;

use App\DBAL\Types\Geolocation\Point;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

class PointType extends Type
{

    const POINT = 'point';

    /**
     * @param array $column
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $column, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return "POINT";
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return self::POINT;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     * @return Point
     */
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        list($longitude, $latitude) = sscanf($value, 'POINT(%f %f)');
        return new Point($latitude, $longitude);
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     * @return string
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $value->getLongitude() . ',' . $value->getLatitude();
    }

    /**
     * @param string $sqlExpr
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     * @return string
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValueSQL($sqlExpr, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return sprintf('PointFromText(%s)', $sqlExpr);
    }
}
```

doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    types:
        point: App\DBAL\Types\PSQL\PointType
```

In my location file I got the property coordinate, like this:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="point")
 */
private $coordinate;

public function getCoordinate(): Point
{
    return $this->coordinate;
}

public function setCoordinate($coordinate): self
{
    $this->coordinate = $coordinate;

    return $this;
}
```

After I call the getCoordinate function and then getLatitude they return me null value. I dont know how to work with It, I try various methods I find on stackoverflow, but anyone works to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED - The problem was on PointType class. I saw the raw data on database and it was in form "(value, value)". Only I need to change was the convertToPHPValue method.

Before:

```
list($longitude, $latitude) = sscanf($value, 'POINT(%f %f)');
```

After:

```
list($longitude, $latitude) = sscanf($value, '(%f, %f)');
```